# R Optimx error : Cannot evaluate function at initial parameters

Tags: r, optimization, optim

I have a project that involves estimating parameters for a Lee_Carter model (mx = exp(ax + bx *kt)). The aim is to predict future values of Life expectancy at birth (e0) without having the Kt parameter, my instructor told me I could use the optimx package to minimize e0_estimated - e0_expert (that I have values for), I first started to look for an equation for e0_estmated starting from the generic Lee_Carter Model which is why I've computed various conversions.

Whenever I run the optimization process using optimx, I keep getting an error message that says:

"Error in optimx.check(par, optcfg$ufn, optcfg$ugr, optcfg$uhess, lower, : Cannot evaluate function at initial parameters."

here's a shortened version of the code I'm working with

```
# Shortened matrices ax et bx
ax <- c(-4.3198094, -5.8995814, -6.1240039, -7.0870399, -7.0525417)
bx <- c(0.04522097, 0.02488256, 0.02452534, -3.2110186, -3.0955417)

data <- data.frame(
  DATE = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2023-01-01")),
  LE = matrix(c(77.76000, 77.05507, 76.34821, 75.64329, 74.93836), ncol = 1)
)
e0_expert <- data$LE

# Convert mx to qx
convert1 <- function(mx, qx, ax, bx, kt) {
  mx <- exp(ax + kt * bx)
  qx <- (2 * mx) / (2 + mx)
  return(qx)
}

# Calculate lx using qx
calculate_lx <- function(qx, l0 = 10000) {
  n <- length(qx)
  lx <- numeric(n) 
  lx[1] <- l0
  lx[2] <- l0 * (1 - qx[1])
  for (i in 2:n) {
    lx[i] <- lx[i - 1] * (1 - qx[i - 1])
  }
  return(lx)
}

# Convert lx to dx
calculate_dx <- function(dx, lx) {
  d0 <- l0 - lx[2]
  n <- length(lx)
  dx <- numeric(n)
  dx[1] <- d0
  for (i in 2:(n-1)) {
    dx[i] <- lx[i] - lx[i+1]
  }
  return(dx)
}

# Convert dx to Lx
calculate_Lx <- function(Lx, dx) {
  L0 <- d0 * lx[2] + 0.5
  n <- length(dx)
  Lx <- numeric(n)
  Lx[1] <- L0
  for (i in 2:n-1){
    Lx[i] <- dx[i] * lx[i+1] + 0.5
  }
  return(Lx)
}

# Convert qx to ex
convert2 <- function(Lx, lx, ex) {
  n <- length(Lx)
  ex <- numeric(n)
  ex <- sum(Lx) / lx
  e0_estime <- ex[1]
  return(e0_estime)
}

# Function to calculate the difference between the estimation and the projection
calculate_error <- function(kt, e0_expert, ax, bx) {
  e0_estime <- convert2(Lx, lx, e0_estime)
  error <- e0_estime - e0_expert
  error_value <- sum(error^2)
  cat("Error:", error_value, "\n")
  if (error_value < 50) { 
    cat("Converged to a solution: kt =", kt, "Error =", error_value, "\n")
  }
  return(error_value)
}

# Perform optimization using the defined function and parameters
result <- optimx(
  par = c(72.047557, 70.373062, 66.536728, 63.807676,   58.721023),
  fn = calculate_error, 
  e0_expert = e0_expert, 
  ax = ax, 
  bx = bx, 
  method = "Nelder-Mead",
  control = list(trace = 2, maxit = 1000, abstol = 1e-100, minimize = TRUE)
)

# kt optimal
optimal_kt <- result$par

cat("Optimal_kt:", optimal_kt, "\n")
```

I've tried various approaches to troubleshoot this error, but it's been persisting, impeding my progress, and I have no idea where the problem may lie (i'm quite new to R, might explain why)

Answer (score 0):

You have the `optimx()` call:

```
optimx(
  par = c(72.047557, 70.373062, 66.536728, 63.807676,   58.721023),
  fn = calculate_error, 
  e0_expert = e0_expert, 
  ax = ax, 
  bx = bx, 
  method = "Nelder-Mead",
  control = list(trace = 2, maxit = 1000, abstol = 1e-100, minimize = TRUE)
)
```

The first value it will try to calculate is

```
calculate_error(c(72.047557, 70.373062, 66.536728, 63.807676,   58.721023), 
                e0_expert = e0_expert, 
                ax = ax, 
                bx = bx)
```

(because `fn` is defined to be `calculate_error`.)  When I try that, I get an error:

```
Error in calculate_error(c(72.047557, 70.373062, 66.536728, 63.807676,  : 
  object 'Lx' not found
```

And that's your problem.  Your objective function uses the variable `Lx` without ever assigning a value to it.

You might get different results, if you happen to have a variable named `Lx` in your workspace.  If it's just an oversight that it didn't get into your question, then you should fix your question to get any help with the real error.  If it's some variable that you forgot about, then you need to rewrite `calculate_error` so that it works without it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes Lx has no value because it depends on dx that depends on lx that also depends on qx that depends on mx that depends on Kt (in other words, the variable I'm trying to extract from the optimx function).  I essentially have many variables with no values, but their values could very much be assigned if I figure out Kt values that would minimize my fn